# Process JSON as single entity in Akka stream rather that iterating over it

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to connect a consumer with a producer using Akka streams.

```
while (true) {
            JsonNode msg = producer.getNextDataEnvelope();
            if (msg == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(msg.toString());
            final Source<JsonNode, NotUsed> source = Source.from(getJSONMessage(msg));
            final Sink<JsonNode, CompletionStage<Done>> sink =
              Sink.foreach(receivedMsg -> consumer.sendJson((ObjectNode) receivedMsg));

            final RunnableGraph<CompletionStage<Done>> runnable = source.toMat(sink, Keep.right());
            final CompletionStage<Done> producerConsumer = runnable.run(system);
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }

        private static ObjectNode getJSONMessage(JsonNode message) {
          JsonNode pipelineMsg = message.get(KEYNAME);
          return (ObjectNode)pipelineMsg;
        }
```

The json produced after getJSONMessage is something like this

```
{
  a: {
  },
  b: {
  }
}

When this JSON goes to consumer it is processing it as
```

a: {
}

First and then

```
b: {
}
```

How would I process the complete JSON payload at once in akka-stream rather then it iterating over the JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Source.from`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#from(java.lang.Iterable)) method creates an Akka Streams `Source` from an `Iterable` object. Since [`ObjectNode`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) implements `Iterable<JsonNode>`, by iterating over its children, your stream will have one element per value in the object.

You can create a `Source` with one element using [`Source.single`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#single(T)), but in that case there's really no benefit to use Akka Streams at all in this method. It would be much more straightforward to pass the node directly to `consumer.sendJson` as in this example:

```
while (true) {
    JsonNode msg = producer.getNextDataEnvelope();
    if (msg == null) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(msg.toString());
    ObjectNode receivedMsg = getJSONMessage(msg);
    consumer.sendJson(receivedMsg);
}

private static ObjectNode getJSONMessage(JsonNode message) {
    JsonNode pipelineMsg = message.get(KEYNAME);
    return (ObjectNode)pipelineMsg;
}
```

On the other hand, if you do want to take advantage of Akka Streams, it would make more sense to turn `producer` into a `Source<JsonNode>`, `consumer` into a `Sink` or `Flow`, and do all of the processing in the stream:

```
producer
     .map(dataEnvelope -> getJSONMessage(dataEnvelope))
     .runWith(consumer, system);
```

Comment: I dont have control over the producer and consumer. They are being provided by a library. I think I can wrap them in an Actor interface. Same can be done with consumer.

Comment: It might be possible to wrap them in Akka Streams stages, too. See the Alpakka project for many examples of this: https://github.com/akka/alpakka

Comment: Yeah these looks helpful https://akka.io/alpakka-samples/